# Authenticate UL-C tag with ACR1255U

Tags: authentication, rfid, mifare, apdu, acr122

I am using a ACR1255U-J1 from ACS and i'm trying to authenticate a UL-C tag via PC/SC transparent commands.

For the moment my commands look like this:

```
command = Optional("FF C2 00 00 02 81 00") // start session
response = C0 03 00 90 00 90 00
command = Optional("FF C2 00 02 04 8F 02 00 03") // ISO 14443-3 Type A switch
response = C0 03 00 90 00 8F 01 00 90 00
command = Optional("FF C2 00 00 02 84 00") // RF ON
response = C0 03 00 90 00 90 00
command = Optional("FF C2 00 01 2A 5F 46 04 00 80 00 00 95 21 1B 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38") // my password is 88888888888888888888888888888888
```

but on the authentication command my reader freeze and I got no response and I have to restart it

Does someone got an idea ?
I read also about the 3DS authentication for the UL-C but i couldn't find a way to communicate with the reader to do it